# Как отправить письмо с логами падения на эл. почту через smtp сервер android?

Tags: android, email, smtp

Я хочу контролировать все падения приложения на устройствах которые установили мое приложение. Для этого я пытаюсь отловить логи падения и отправить себе на почту. Раньше я пользовался такой функцией:

```
public void SendLogcatMail(Throwable e) {
        String stackTrace = Log.getStackTraceString(e);
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"angoran16@gmail.com"});
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Problem with your application");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, stackTrace);
        try {
            emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

но столкнулся с такой проблемой - не на всех устройствах установлены почтовые клиенты, и возникают проблемы из-за этого. Что я хочу сделать - каким-то образом (пока не сосем понял каким) слать тихо логи на заранее известную почту, чтобы я получил логи падения уже при падении и мог обновить приложение. Я так почитал что в решении моей проблемы мне поможет smtp сервер, но так и не понял почему именно такой вид серверов. Вот есть [ресурс](https://gafurbabu.wordpress.com/tag/send-email-via-smtp-in-android/) который я нашел и вот еще https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083547/send-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-with-smtp-but-without-ssl и еще https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136025/sending-mail-in-android-without-intents-using-smtp но постоянно лезут малопонятные ошибки которые возникают в процессе внедрения вышеуказанного функционала. Вот например, я так понимаю это ошибка:

```
W: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
W:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
W:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
W:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
W:     at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:816)
W:     at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(InternetAddress.java:517)
W:     at javax.mail.internet.UniqueValue.getUniqueMessageIDValue(UniqueValue.java:99)
W:     at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateMessageID(MimeMessage.java:2054)
W:     at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2076)
W:     at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2042)
W:     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:117)
W:     at com.example.developer_4.test_login.utils.GMailSender.send(GMailSender.java:109)
W:     at com.example.developer_4.test_login.SecondScreenActivity.MainScreen.onOptionsItemSelected(MainScreen.java:214)
W:     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3204)
W:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:436)
W:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:196)
W:     at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
W:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:888)
W:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
W:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
W:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
W:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:981)
W:     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:625)
W:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:151)
W:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
W:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
W:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
W:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
W:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

судя по тексту ошибки мое письмо так и не отправилось адресату, то есть мне. В большинстве способов от пользователя необходимо ввести свой гугловский email и пароль, что подразумевает логин на сервере, а это лишнее действие со стороны пользователя. Надеюсь что уже есть рабочее решение которое можно использовать у себя в работе.

### update

после некоторых поисков в сети я понял что можно вообще отправлять письма без tls аутентификации, но пока не понял как именно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отправка на почту логов это довольно громоздкий процесс, и не всегда устройство отдаст логи без проблем. Я принял решение использовать сервис `fabric.io`. Это самое идеальное решение для таких задач. Подключение довольно простое, там есть инструкция, но как результат вы получаете не только ловушку для краша, но так же вы получаете и много других плюшек - статистику посещаемости например. Может кому-то эта информация окажется полезной. Удачи всем начинающим разработчикам :D