# Как отправить отчёт себе на почту в Windows Forms без ввода пароля C#?

Tags: c#, smtp, email

У меня есть программа, которая собирает отчет о своей работе (логи ошибок) и мне нужно эти данные (логи программы) слать себе на почту для анализа без вода каких-либо паролей.

Как это сделать?

p.s.: Сам я на почту слать могу, но только с паролем самого отправителя (что конечно же логично, ведь надо пройти авторизацию сначала). 
Но в моём случае, я хочу это сделать без ввода пароля. Чтобы программа отправляла эти логи мне на почту.

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Как без ключа войти в квартиру запертую на ключ? Подымите свой почтовый сервер, который не будет требовать пароль на отправку - и наслаждайтесь тоннами спама, которые через вас будут слать кроме вас - пока вас не забанят поисковики, а то и придёт интерпол с вопросами "кто-то отправлял письма про наркотики через ваш сервер". Или создайтё учётку с паролем и шлите от её имени письма на этот же почтовый ящик.

Comment: `using System.Net.Mail; ` гуглите

Comment: @AK, нет. Я никогда "заходить без ключа" не собираюсь. Мне просто нужен способ отправки логов программы на почту себе. Но только без каких либо паролей. Чтобы я не писал никаких паролей... А то обычно при отправке все требуют ввода пароля.

Comment: `WF` - это [Windows Workflow Foundation](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Workflow_Foundation)

Comment: @tym32167 подозреваю что эт windows forms

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц я знаю про него и им пользуюсь...

Comment: чем же не подходит чтобы слать ваши логи?

Comment: Напишите прямо: ваш вопрос в том, что вы не умеете отправлять письма из программного кода ([тынц1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/457072/213987), [тынц2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%8B)) или вам нужно [сокрытие пароля в конфиге](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/966979/213987)?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц я потому и указал автору, что не то он сокращение использует.

Comment: @tym32167 про сокращение понял, учту.

Comment: без пароля вы письмо не отправите, чтобы отправить письмо, надо авторизоваться на почтовом сервере.

Comment: @AK, ладно, я понял как.
Буду использовать - https://get.fabric.io
Там есть все ))

Comment: Будьте любезны, оформите ответ, как вы решили проблему с помощью fabric.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, к сожалению - никак. Я подглядел ответ здесь (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/911686/Как-отправить-письмо-с-логами-падения-на-эл-почту-через-smtp-сервер-android?rq=1) почти на такую же тему вопроса как у меня и там был указан fabric.io. Я с ним повозился и понял, что данная платформа очень гибка и удобна, но годится только для андройд, iOS и Unity проектов. Для других я так и не смог её настроить (я тупень, сразу не заметил что данная платформа только для телефонов...). Поэтому пришлось оставить эту затею и убрать свой модуль отправки логов на почту из программы...

Answer (score 1):

Как ни странно, это возможно. Просто вместо **использования** SMTP-сервера нужно **взять на себя** его работу: определить целевой SMTP-сервер путем запроса MX-записи, подключиться к нему и передать данные. Для этого понадобится два вспомогательных класса:

Для получения MX-записей (взято с https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/89b21138-596f-4efc-8e86-d440d260c41e/how-to-find-smtp-mail-server-name-and-port?forum=csharpgeneral)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleTest1
{
    public static class Mx
    {

        [DllImport("dnsapi", EntryPoint = "DnsQuery_W", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern int DnsQuery([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)]ref string pszName, QueryTypes wType, QueryOptions options, int aipServers, ref IntPtr ppQueryResults, int pReserved);

        [DllImport("dnsapi", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern void DnsRecordListFree(IntPtr pRecordList, int FreeType);

        public static string[] GetMXRecords(string domain)
        {

            IntPtr ptr1 = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr ptr2 = IntPtr.Zero;
            MXRecord recMx;
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform != PlatformID.Win32NT)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
            ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
            int num1 = Mx.DnsQuery(ref domain, QueryTypes.DNS_TYPE_MX, QueryOptions.DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE, 0, ref ptr1, 0);
            if (num1 != 0)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(num1.ToString());
            }
            for (ptr2 = ptr1; !ptr2.Equals(IntPtr.Zero); ptr2 = recMx.pNext)
            {
                recMx = (MXRecord)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr2, typeof(MXRecord));
                if (recMx.wType == 15)
                {
                    string text1 = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(recMx.pNameExchange);
                    list1.Add(text1);
                }
            }
            Mx.DnsRecordListFree(ptr2, 0);
            return (string[])list1.ToArray(typeof(string));
        }

        private enum QueryOptions
        {
            DNS_QUERY_ACCEPT_TRUNCATED_RESPONSE = 1,
            DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE = 8,
            DNS_QUERY_DONT_RESET_TTL_VALUES = 0x100000,
            DNS_QUERY_NO_HOSTS_FILE = 0x40,
            DNS_QUERY_NO_LOCAL_NAME = 0x20,
            DNS_QUERY_NO_NETBT = 0x80,
            DNS_QUERY_NO_RECURSION = 4,
            DNS_QUERY_NO_WIRE_QUERY = 0x10,
            DNS_QUERY_RESERVED = -16777216,
            DNS_QUERY_RETURN_MESSAGE = 0x200,
            DNS_QUERY_STANDARD = 0,
            DNS_QUERY_TREAT_AS_FQDN = 0x1000,
            DNS_QUERY_USE_TCP_ONLY = 2,
            DNS_QUERY_WIRE_ONLY = 0x100
        }

        private enum QueryTypes
        {
            DNS_TYPE_MX = 15
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct MXRecord
        {
            public IntPtr pNext;
            public string pName;
            public short wType;
            public short wDataLength;
            public int flags;
            public int dwTtl;
            public int dwReserved;
            public IntPtr pNameExchange;
            public short wPreference;
            public short Pad;
        }
    }
}
```

Для отправки почты по SMTP (слегка модифицированный класс отсюда: http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20030316.asp)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Web.Mail;

namespace SMTP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// provides methods to send email via smtp direct to mail server
    /// </summary>
    public class SmtpDirect
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get / Set the name of the SMTP mail server
        /// </summary>
        public static string SmtpServer;

        public static StringBuilder output;

        private enum SMTPResponse : int
        {
            CONNECT_SUCCESS = 220,
            GENERIC_SUCCESS = 250,
            DATA_SUCCESS = 354,
            QUIT_SUCCESS = 221
        }
        public static bool Send(MailMessage message)
        {
            output = new StringBuilder(300);
            IPHostEntry IPhst = Dns.Resolve(SmtpServer);
            IPEndPoint endPt = new IPEndPoint(IPhst.AddressList[0], 25);
            Socket s = new Socket(endPt.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            s.Connect(endPt);

            if (!Check_Response(s, SMTPResponse.CONNECT_SUCCESS))
            {
                s.Close();
                return false;
            }

            Senddata(s, "HELO example.com\r\n");
            output.AppendLine("HELO");

            if (!Check_Response(s, SMTPResponse.GENERIC_SUCCESS))
            {
                s.Close();
                return false;
            }

            Senddata(s, string.Format("MAIL From: {0}\r\n", message.From));
            output.AppendLine("MAIL From");
            if (!Check_Response(s, SMTPResponse.GENERIC_SUCCESS))
            {

                s.Close();
                return false;
            }

            string _To = message.To;
            string[] Tos = _To.Split(new char[] { ';' });
            foreach (string To in Tos)
            {
                Senddata(s, string.Format("RCPT TO: {0}\r\n", To));
                output.AppendLine("RCPT TO");
                if (!Check_Response(s, SMTPResponse.GENERIC_SUCCESS))
                {
                    s.Close();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            if (message.Cc != null)
            {
                Tos = message.Cc.Split(new char[] { ';' });
                foreach (string To in Tos)
                {
                    Senddata(s, string.Format("RCPT TO: {0}\r\n", To));
                    output.AppendLine("RCPT TO");
                    if (!Check_Response(s, SMTPResponse.GENERIC_SUCCESS))
                    {
                        s.Close();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            StringBuilder Header = new StringBuilder();
            Header.Append("From: " + message.From + "\r\n");
            Tos = message.To.Split(new char[] { ';' });
            Header.Append("To: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < Tos.Length; i++)
            {
                Header.Append(i > 0 ? "," : "");
                Header.Append(Tos[i]);
            }
            Header.Append("\r\n");
            if (message.Cc != null)
            {
                Tos = message.Cc.Split(new char[] { ';' });
                Header.Append("Cc: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < Tos.Length; i++)
                {
                    Header.Append(i > 0 ? "," : "");
                    Header.Append(Tos[i]);
                }
                Header.Append("\r\n");
            }
            Header.Append("Date: ");
            Header.Append(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, d M y H:m:s z"));
            Header.Append("\r\n");
            Header.Append("Subject: " + message.Subject + "\r\n");
            Header.Append("X-Mailer: SMTPDirect v1\r\n");
            string MsgBody = message.Body;
            if (!MsgBody.EndsWith("\r\n"))
                MsgBody += "\r\n";
            if (message.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                Header.Append("MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n");
                Header.Append("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=unique-boundary-1\r\n");
                Header.Append("\r\n");
                Header.Append("This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("--unique-boundary-1\r\n");
                sb.Append("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n");
                sb.Append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7Bit\r\n");
                sb.Append("\r\n");
                sb.Append(MsgBody + "\r\n");
                sb.Append("\r\n");

                foreach (object o in message.Attachments)
                {
                    MailAttachment a = o as MailAttachment;
                    byte[] binaryData;
                    if (a != null)
                    {
                        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(a.Filename);
                        sb.Append("--unique-boundary-1\r\n");
                        sb.Append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; file=" + f.Name + "\r\n");
                        sb.Append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n");
                        sb.Append("Content-Dispos" + "ition: attachment; filename=" + f.Name + "\r\n");
                        sb.Append("\r\n");
                        FileStream fs = f.OpenRead();
                        binaryData = new Byte[fs.Length];
                        long bytesRead = fs.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)fs.Length);
                        fs.Close();
                        string base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);

                        for (int i = 0; i < base64String.Length; )
                        {
                            int nextchunk = 100;
                            if (base64String.Length - (i + nextchunk) < 0)
                                nextchunk = base64String.Length - i;
                            sb.Append(base64String.Substring(i, nextchunk));
                            sb.Append("\r\n");
                            i += nextchunk;
                        }
                        sb.Append("\r\n");
                    }
                }
                MsgBody = sb.ToString();
            }

            Senddata(s, ("DATA\r\n"));
            output.AppendLine("DATA");
            if (!Check_Response(s, SMTPResponse.DATA_SUCCESS))
            {
                s.Close();
                return false;
            }
            Header.Append("\r\n");
            Header.Append(MsgBody);
            Header.Append(".\r\n");
            Header.Append("\r\n");
            Header.Append("\r\n");
            Senddata(s, Header.ToString());
            if (!Check_Response(s, SMTPResponse.GENERIC_SUCCESS))
            {
                s.Close();
                return false;
            }

            Senddata(s, "QUIT\r\n");
            output.AppendLine("QUIT");
            Check_Response(s, SMTPResponse.QUIT_SUCCESS);
            s.Close();
            return true;
        }
        private static void Senddata(Socket s, string msg)
        {
            byte[] _msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            s.Send(_msg, 0, _msg.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        }
        private static bool Check_Response(Socket s, SMTPResponse response_expected)
        {
            string sResponse;
            int response;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while (s.Available == 0)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            s.Receive(bytes, 0, s.Available, SocketFlags.None);
            sResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

            sResponse = sResponse.Replace("\0", "");
            output.Append(sResponse);

            response = Convert.ToInt32(sResponse.Substring(0, 3));
            if (response != (int)response_expected)
                return false;
            return true;
        }


    }
}
```

Использование:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mail;
using SMTP;

namespace ConsoleTest1
{
    class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string dest = "pupkin@example.com";
            string[] elems = dest.Split("@".ToCharArray());
            string[] arr = Mx.GetMXRecords(elems[1]);

            string s = "";
            foreach (string x in arr) s += x + Environment.NewLine;
            Console.WriteLine("MX records:" + Environment.NewLine + s);

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To = dest;
            msg.From = "pupkin@example.com";
            msg.Subject = "Hello, world";
            msg.Body = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
            SmtpDirect.SmtpServer = arr[0];

            SmtpDirect.Send(msg);
            Console.WriteLine(SmtpDirect.output.ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Недостаток в том, что отправленное таким образом письмо гарантированно попадет в спам, а также рядом с адресом отправителя будет отображаться предупреждение, что он "подделан".

Comment: Спасибо! Интересный способ, обязательно попробую когда буду дома. ))
[не пойму, за что проминусовали мой вопрос... ]